# What is the physics behind Oasis Mini?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

A ball placed in the sand is moving around and drawing magnificent art. In the video below it draws a dolphin. It is very precise.

How does it work?

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/2b291H4uHAY